# Group data with checkboxes and drag/drop functionality in C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, listview, gridview

I have a table of data that I want to display as groups in an asp.net web page. The sql database table has columns for items and item_product. I'd like to show a list of items that belong to each item_product. Each item in the group needs a checkbox to enable selection and all items in the group can also be selected/unselected with a "check all" checkbox. I would also like to be able to expand/collapse each group. It would also be great if I could drop and drop all the items so I could re-order them easily.
I've already googled this to death and I just don't see a suitable solution that fits my needs. I don't mind what data control is used or if jquery or whatever is used, as long as the end result does what I want.
I know I'm being awkward but if you think have a solution, could you please post the entire code please? I'm just starting on ASP.NET and C# and would love to have this working before the end of the year.

Comment: OK, maybe I was asking for too much. If I could see code to display my data in groups, I think I could figure out the rest myself. As I said, I don't mind what data control I use.

Answer (score 0):

for acheiving the desired functionality you need to purchase third party gridview control. the options are devexpress,telerik and jqgrid

i personally use devexpress